# WHERE clause not showing all rows when joining two tables? Do I need a left join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure what the title is for this question.

**Updated to show more concrete problem.**

I have 2 tables.

table_a

```
+------------+--------+---------+
| date       | used   | solar   |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 2012-03-16 | 20.317 |  -4.167 |
| 2012-03-17 | 17.308 | -38.593 |
| 2012-03-18 |  9.529 | -42.414 |
| 2012-03-19 | 13.266 | -26.372 |
| 2012-03-20 |  7.077 | -41.742 |
| 2012-03-21 |  7.625 | -43.348 |
| 2012-03-22 | 10.943 | -42.025 |
| 2012-03-23 | 11.362 | -38.532 |
| 2012-03-24 | 11.492 |  -9.434 |
| 2012-03-25 | 16.133 |  -8.280 |
| 2012-03-26 | 17.054 | -31.340 |
| 2012-03-27 |  9.356 | -49.759 |
| 2012-03-28 | 11.984 | -16.299 |
| 2012-03-29 | 20.175 |  -6.412 |
| 2012-03-30 | 16.024 | -47.509 |
| 2012-03-31 | 10.605 | -16.102 |
+------------+--------+---------+
```

table_b

```
+------------+--------+
| date       | hdd    |
+------------+--------+
| 2012-03-01 | 32.884 |
| 2012-03-02 | 31.402 |
| 2012-03-03 | 22.487 |
| 2012-03-04 | 31.087 |
| 2012-03-05 | 41.679 |
| 2012-03-06 | 39.892 |
| 2012-03-07 | 17.626 |
| 2012-03-08 |  8.433 |
| 2012-03-09 | 29.580 |
| 2012-03-10 | 35.238 |
| 2012-03-11 | 22.453 |
| 2012-03-12 | 11.724 |
| 2012-03-13 |  6.486 |
| 2012-03-14 | 16.140 |
| 2012-03-15 | 21.425 |
| 2012-03-16 | 20.486 |
| 2012-03-17 | 13.744 |
| 2012-03-18 |  8.207 |
| 2012-03-19 |  3.878 |
| 2012-03-20 |  2.679 |
| 2012-03-21 |  2.701 |
| 2012-03-22 |  2.830 |
| 2012-03-23 |  4.219 |
| 2012-03-24 | 15.008 |
| 2012-03-25 | 19.155 |
| 2012-03-26 | 27.850 |
| 2012-03-27 | 32.985 |
| 2012-03-28 | 20.470 |
| 2012-03-29 | 26.230 |
| 2012-03-30 | 26.119 |
| 2012-03-31 | 24.353 |
+------------+--------+
```

`table_a` has 16 records. `table_b` has 31 records.

If I use...

```
SELECT a.date, a.used, b.hdd
FROM table_a a RIGHT JOIN table_b b ON a.date=b.date
WHERE MONTH(a.date) = 3;
```

I only get 16 rows, presumably because table_a only has 16 rows. But actually it must be the where clause. How do I use the two together?

How do I get all 31 rows (*assuming dates match from each table for the other 16 rows*). I tried a left join but that didn't work.

```
SELECT a.date, a.used, b.hdd FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.date=b.date;
```

Answer (score 4):

use `RIGHT JOIN` instead since you want to show all 10 records from `table_b`

```
SELECT a.date, a.column1, b.column1 
FROM table_a a RIGHT JOIN table_b b ON a.date=b.date;
```

or interchange the tablenames so you can still use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT b.date, b.column1, a.column1 
FROM table_b a LEFT JOIN table_a b ON a.date=b.date;
```

**SIDENOTE**

The reason why you are only getting 5 records when you run this query,

```
SELECT a.date, a.column1, b.column1 
FROM table_a a, table_b b 
WHERE a.date=b.date;
```

is because it performs like `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT a.date, a.column1, b.column1 
FROM table_a a INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.date=b.date
```

An `INNER JOIN` selects on rows that has atleast one match on the other table being joined. To fully understand about joins, please see the article below.

- [**Visual Representation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: +1. @user1836259: Note that this will inject SQL NULLs in your output.

Comment: @BillyONeal yep, I agree. But with the use of `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` the OP can customized the column he wants to show for null values `:D`

Comment: I've tried every kind of join, including right. Still getting only 5 rows that correspond to table_a.

Comment: I'm fine with seeing nulls in the output. I just need all 10 rows.

Comment: Good point, I think I left something out. I'm also using a where clause, WHERE MONTH(e.date) = 3; for example. It's this that is only returning the 5 rows right? I need a where clause, but maybe I'm using it wrong with the join.

Comment: maybe it's because of the `WHERE` clause that filters it out. Can you show sample records? This could help a lot in solving your problem `:D`

Comment: Ugh, just figured it out. Where clause was using table_a.date, when it should have used table_b.date, which works. I was trying to solve the wrong problem. Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.date, a.used, b.hdd FROM table_b b
LEFT JOIN table_a a ON b.date=a.date AND MONTH(a.date) = 3;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT a.date, a.used, b.hdd
FROM table_a a RIGHT JOIN table_b b ON a.date=b.date
WHERE MONTH(b.date) = 3;
```